# What is the index name of this add_index command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Schema I have this:

```
 add_index "key_performance_indicators", ["organization_id"], :name => "index_key_performance_inds_on_organization_id"
```

And I want to write a remove_index migration to remove this index but can't figure out what is the index name that I should use?  Is it `key_performance_inds` or `performance_inds_on_organization_id` ? or something else?

And if I use a visual admin tool this is what it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed the `:name` option to `add_index` so the name of the index is what you set. In this case it is `index_key_performance_inds_on_organization_id` therefore to remove it:

`remove_index 'key_performance_indicators', :name => 'index_key_performance_inds_on_organization_id'`

Answer (score 2):

Tomdarkness has provided the right answer but you might want to omit the `:name` part altogether unless there is a need to conform to a specific database schema.  `add_index` will choose a sensible index name by default for you and `remove_index` will use that same default.

For example:

```
add_index :key_performance_indicators, :organization_id
```

The above line will add the index with the name `index_key_performance_indicators_on_organization_id` and the following will remove it:

```
remove_index :key_performance_indicators, :organization_id
```